# Push-notifications stop working, Private key missing

Tags: push-notification, certificate, app-store-connect, p12

I'm in big trouble, I've one application already live in Apple store. Suddenly, My Mac's hard-disk is got crashed, So, I'v replaced it with another hard disk.

When i execute my project from new system (new hard-disk), xCode has created some certificates and profile Automatically, So, As reaction, push notifications stop immediately.

But problem is, I don't have my old certificate and private key (.p12). So, I'm unable send any push notifications or test it.

Please guide me if some one has idea about this kind of issue.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If from your mac there is all actual certificate are removed. then you have to create new CSR and generate all the certificate and use it with existing appid.

If you have old csr then create new cer for push and make it PEM file and use that new one at the server side.

- You need to create New CSR.
- Generate New Certificate for Dis and Dev.
- Generate new push Certificate.
- Now use that all by double click that will be show your private key.
- Generate New provisional profile using new cer and use it.

Comment: Problem is, I don't have any old CSR or p12 files. If i tried with New CSR and PEM file. It's giving error like, Private key is missing.

Comment: yes i note down the steps you need to generate new one all the stuff.

Comment: @Sonu my notification is not working suddenly in android after converting to my project to android X